# awk invert regular expression pattern rule

Tags: awk, pattern-matching

i have code like this:

```
awk '(/\/\*\!/),(/\*\/\;/)'
```

that will match everything like this:

```
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
/*!50001 CREATE TABLE `sometable` (
  `id` int(11),
  `name` char(30),
  `user` char(30),
) ENGINE=MyISAM */;
```

How can I invert the matching of my awk code above? I tried:

```
awk '!(/\/\*\!/),(/\*\/\;/)'
awk '!(/\/\*\!/),!(/\*\/\;/)'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a variable

```
awk '/\/\*!/{a=1}!a;/\*\/;/{a=0}' test.in
```

A couple other notes:

- You don't need the parentheses
- You don't need to escape `!` or `;`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
awk '(/\/\*\!/),(/\*\/\;/){next}{print}'
```